# Alternatinve proof for the principle of the Iterated Suprema

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-verification, alternative-proof

The back of the book gave a proof similar to the proof here [Proving principle of the Iterated Suprema](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426722/proving-principle-of-the-iterated-suprema), but I proved it following way before I checked the back of the book. Could some one verify this proof?

Let $X,Y\neq\emptyset$
  and let $f:X\times Y\to\mathbb{R}$
  have a bounded range in $\mathbb{R}$
  . Also, let

$f_{1}(x)=\sup\{f(x,y):\: y\in Y\}$
  and $f_{2}(y)=\sup\{f(x,y):\: x\in X\}$

Prove that 
\begin{align*} \sup\{f(x,y):\: x\in X,y\in Y\}&=&\sup\{f_{1}(x):\: x\in X\}\\&=&\sup\{f_{2}(y):\: y\in Y\} \end{align*}

*proof*.  Since $\text{Ran}f$
  is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$
  we have that the set $\{f(x,y):\: x\in X,y\in Y\}$
  indeed has a supremum (and an infimum). If we let $u=\sup\{f(x,y):\: x\in X,y\in Y\}$
  then we have that $(\forall x\in X)(\forall y\in Y)(f(x,y)\leqslant u)$
 , this implies that $(\forall x\in X)(f_{1}(x)\leqslant u)$
  and $(\forall y\in Y)(f_{2}(y)\leqslant u)$
 , hence $\sup f_{1}(x)\leqslant u$
  and $\sup f_{2}(y)\leqslant u$
 . Now suppose $\sup f_{1}(x)<u$
  Then there exist a $x'$
  such that $f(x',y)\leqslant u'<u$
  for all $x$
  and $y$
  hence $u'$
  is an upper bound on $f(x,y)$
 , but this contradicts our selection of $u$
  as the supremum of $\{f(x,y):\: x\in X,y\in Y\}$
 , thus $(u\leqslant\sup f_{1}(x)\leqslant u)\implies\sup f_{1}(x)=u$
 . Likewise, if we suppose that $\sup f_{2}(y)<u$
  then $(\exists y')(\forall x,y)(f(x,y)\leqslant f(x,y')<u)$
  which means that $f(x,y')$
  is an upper bound on $f(x,y)$
  again this contradicts our selection of $u$
  as $\sup\{f(x,y):\: x\in X,y\in Y\}$
 . Consequetly, we have that $(u\leqslant\sup f_{2}(y)\leqslant u)\implies(\sup f_{2}(y)=u)$
 . So indeed we have that 
\begin{align*} \sup\{f(x,y):\: x\in X,y\in Y\}&=&\sup\{f_{1}(x):\: x\in X\}\\&=&\sup\{f_{2}(y):\: y\in Y\} \end{align*}

Comment: Could we not actually say, if $u$ is the smallest upper bound and $\sup f_1(x)$ is some upper bound of $f(x,y)$, that $u\leq \sup f_1(x)$. Even if $ u=\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof you give is correct.